# MATLAB sinc issue

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I'm trying to plot the sinc function in the image below using the code below, but not getting it. Any suggestions?

[image]

```
X = -5:1/150:5;
Y = 2*150e6*pi*sinc(150e6*X);
```

Comment: `Y = 2*150e6*pi*sinc(X)` will give the solid curve, up to a vertical scale factor

Comment: What exactly do you mean by vertical scale factor? When I plot Y = 2*150e6*pi*sinc(X), I get 942800000 as my max value at 0...

Comment: See my previous comment. I mean `Y = 2*150e6*pi*sinc(X)`, not `Y = 2*150e6*pi*sinc(150e6*X)`. The horizontal scale is now correct

Comment: Yes I plotted Y = 2*150e6*pi*sinc(X) and I get I get 942800000 as my max value at X = 0.

Comment: Please pay more attention when picking tags. You picked "signals" and "Processing" without bothering to check what they meant. The first is about software interrupts, the second for the programming language called Processing. You should have instead used "signal-processing"

Comment: My fault. I'll be more careful next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
hold all
c = 3e8; %// speed of light, m/s
x = -5:1/150:5;
t = x/c;
for B = [150e6 300e6 600e6]; %// bandwidth, Hz
    y = 2*pi*B*sinc(B*t);
    plot(x,y)
end
grid
legend('B = 150 MHz', 'B = 300 MHz', 'B = 600 MHz')
xlabel('$x = ct$','interpreter','latex')
ylabel('$2\pi B \mathrm{sinc}(Bt)$','interpreter','latex')
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help. I just realized the 'c' factor.

Comment: Yes, actually the two axis labels in the original graph tell all that's needed :-)